# Can anyone suggest book about fixed-income portfolio management?

Tags: fixed-income, portfolio-management, bond, portfolio, fixed

Can anyone suggest books about fixed-income portfolio management?

Thx

Comment: Bruce Tuckman and Angel Serrat ; Fixed Income Securities